# Programmatically storing a list into my combobox's item collection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am working on a Windows Form right now, specifically, a combo box.

Traditionally, one can use/access/define items or strings into the collection through Visual Studio's GUI in the Properties menu. With that said, I would like to do this programatically.

I have two `List<string>`. Let's say the first `List` are names, and the second `List` are ages.

1. How does one store the entire first `List` into the collection, so I can use the `comboBox` to access them?
2. Upon clicking on an item in this collection, for example, the fifth name, how do I `get` the index of this item?

So far, I have created my form, and laid the skeleton of the win forms application, but the part of storing the list into the collection is stopping me from moving forward - thank you.

[image]

Comment: `List<String> mNames = new List<String>() {'test','test1'};
ComboBox1.DataSource = mNames;`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage. You can just do `comboBox.DataSource = myList`. Done

Comment: @theGreenCabbage If you like loops, you can still do it in one line using Linq: `myList.ForEach(_ => combobox.Items.Add(_));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++)
{
    combobox.Items.Add(list[i]);
}
```

And to get the index you could use:

```
combobox.selectedindex;
```

I just typed this straight up so use it as a guide more than a copy + paste job :)

Comment: Out of curiosity - do you put this in the `forms` page? As in under         `private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){}`

Comment: I have a method called `ShowForm()`, and inside I have a `for-loop` that counts how many items are in the String List, and does `myForm.comboBox1Object.Items.Add(_firstList[i]);`, but that does not work, as the comboBox is still empty.

Comment: Yes put it on the forms page, you should be able to put it almost anywhere on the forms page as long as it is inside a method but as you are populating a combo box with nothing in it you should populate it with the for loop in a different method first, not the     SelectedIndex change

Comment: hope you understand that ^ ! :)

Answer (score 2):

For the list of strings it can be done like this

```
comboBox.DataSource = myList;
```

If you don't want to tie your list in Datasource, still one line

```
comboBox.DataSource = myList.ToArray().Clone();
```

Now, if this is list of `Strings` you can get the whole string

```
string s = (string)comboBox.SelectedItem; // vs comboBox.SelectedIndex
```